# Getting text with Beautifulsoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I am currently new to Html and python. I would like to do some webscraping project but had some problem to get a text from a html.
My html is as shown below.

```
<ul class="icons">
  <li><span class="img"><img src="https://google/meter-s.png" alt="" title="" class=""></span>71.63%</li>
  <li><span class="img"><img src="https://google/money-s.png" alt="" title="" class=""></span>RM 799,000</li>
  <li><span class="img"><img src="google/rental-s.png" alt="" title="" class=""></span>€ 2,000/mth</li>
  <li><span class="img"><img src="https://google/yield-s.png" alt="" title="" class=""></span>3%</li>
</ul>   /*
```

And I would like to read/get the 3% text at the end of the list. I tried with this

```
soup.find(attrs={'li':None}).find('span', class_ = "img").next_sibling
```

but I however end up getting only the first value in the list which is 71.63%. I hope anyone expert in this topic could help me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just grab all of the `li` elements, select the last one, and grab the text from there. You can do that like this:

```
soup.find_all('li')[-1].text
```